# angular.js:14642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when calling back-end service from angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-promise

I am calling a back-end service using angular and I am encountering an error. the response comes to my service but from there I cannot get the response to my angular controller due to the above promise error.

angular service

```
function userRegister(data) {
  $http.post('/api/user/register',data).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); //the success response comes here
    return response;
  });
}
```

angular controller

```
vm.register = function register() {
  console.log(vm.user);

  commonService.userRegister(vm.user).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); //the promise error comes here
  });
}
```

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should `return` your service also

```
function userRegister(data) {
 return $http.post('/api/user/register',data).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); //the success response comes here
    return response;
  });
}
```

Comment: hey that worked..thanks a lot..I can only accept your answer in 8 more minutes..I will then :D

Comment: Thanks dude! Enjoy the day :)